# Export HTTP headers names into environment variables

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there a way to export HTTP headers **names** into some environment variables? For example, I receive headers:

```
Accept: text/html 
Accept-Language: en 
User-Agent: GoogleBot
```

I need to have environment variable, which contains all headers names, for this example:

```
header_names=Accept,Accept-Language,User-Agent
```

Or if not possible, a set of variables each of them contain 1 header name like

```
header_name_1=Accept
header_name_2=Accept-Language
header_name_3=User-Agent
```

Comment: They are already available as environment variables.  You didn't say what language or program you are looking for these variables in.

Comment: PHP. In PHP devs have SERVER array, however, headers names are capitalized there, while I need them not capitalized, but strictly exactly as they were sent by client.

Comment: Here are [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) in the comments of folks setting those environment variables to other names, which certainly could be any lower case name you wish, aside from any reserved env var names.

Comment: No, what I need is to export HTTP headers names to ENV variable(s). By default Apache export headers with their values into SERVER array, but headers names are capitalized there, while I need to have headers in original letter case. There is no pb to get it from PHP afterwards, but I need to know how to export them from Apache.